# How to add execute permission to root user to /sbim/dmesg directory?

Tags: permissions, amd-ryzen, proxmox, truenas

How to add execute permission to root user to /sbim/dmesg directory?

I am setting up TrueNas via Proxmox; I need to see if mps report any errors.

[Screenshoot of CLI of TrueNas with error of/sbin/dmesg directory and root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BR1t.png)

Comment: Is ``/sbim/dmesg`` a typo? Do you mean ``/sbin/dmesg``.